# Полупрозрачный размытый фон с шумами

Tags: c#, wpf

когда-то давно уже задавался этим вопросом, но без особых успехов. Речь идёт о полупрозрачном размытом фоне, да ещё и с шумами(собственно как на картинке). Подскажите, как можно достичь подобного результата в `WPF`?

Я знаю, что в `UWP` есть какая-то встроенная функция, которая позволяет достичь такого результата, а как на счёт классических приложений `WPF`? Какой наиболее оптимальный способ, в плане производительности, достижения подобного эффекта?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот эффект называется *Acrylic*, часть *Fluent Design System*.

У вас есть 3 способа получить его:

1. Создать свой ShaderEffect, который будет реализовывать шум (Noise) с помощью текстуры. Подобную реализацию можно посмотреть у данного [проекта](https://github.com/bbougot/AcrylicWPF) ([сам эффект шума](https://github.com/bbougot/AcrylicWPF/blob/master/NoiseEffect.cs)).
2. Вы можете установить готовые решения, к примеру [FluentWPF](https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF) (есть в NuGet).
3. Вы можете попробовать с помощью [Desktop Bridge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-my/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) конвертировать ваше приложение в UWP, что даст вам весь функционал данной системы (Toast, Fluent Design и многое другое).

---

На конференции Build 2018 была [анонсирована](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2018/05/07/microsoft-365-empowers-developers-to-build-intelligent-apps-for-where-and-how-the-world-works/) возможность реализации *Fluent Design* в классических программах (Windows Forms, WPF или нативный Win32.).